# iOS white screen debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sometimes, when I run app, I got white screen. But I know app is still running (coz I need to play sound).

Somehow, the view hierarchy mess up I guess. Problem is that I never see white screen if I run from Xcode. If I see, I will know how is the hierarchy.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //need to run in main thread.

self.window.rootViewController = self.defaultVC;
[self.window makeKeyWindow];
self.window.hidden = NO;

});
```

Is it because of view hierarchy? Or any other reason which can produce white screen?

Comment: There should be many reasons of white screen..you need to provide more code & description

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome little tool called [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger) which enables view-based debugging. You just throw it all in your project and start it in your AppDelegate and you can see at anytime exactly what view is displayed.
You can basically step through the hierarchy like in "chrome F12".
This helped me solve WhiteScreen-problems in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Copy Bundle Resources (found within Build Phases) and make sure that all of your .xib files are correctly listed (e.g. that they are indeed there).

Also is there a specific reason you are creating that window programmatically instead of using setRootViewController?

Comment: It is because I need to show some custom view for launch screen (need to support iOS 7 and above).

Comment: There should be many reasons of white screen..you need to provide more code & description

Comment: I plan to provide more code. Problem is I really don't know what can cause white screen. Look like I need to copy paste all codes.